# Wrong number of arguments when run compass watch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compass-sass, compass, celluloid

When I run "compass watch" I got this error:

```
LoadError on line ["54"] of /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I managed to fix it with:

```
sudo gem update
sudo gem install susy
```

When I run compass again, css files were generated and I got a new error:

```
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
    write css/ie10_and_higher.css
    write css/ie9.css
    write css/style.css
D, [2015-07-31T10:36:12.805795 #5675] DEBUG -- : Celluloid 0.17.0 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
ArgumentError on line ["48"] of /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

And now I can't find any solution in google.

Comment: "Run with --trace to see the full backtrace"

Comment: Did you run with the full trace? It will help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too. I had updated everything - ruby, gem --system, all the gems, compass, etc, but it still kept throwing the error. What I had to do was use "gem uninstall listen" repeatedly to remove the multiple 2.7.x versions that were installed - once they were all removed and only listen 3.x existed would it work correctly again.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it's an issue with the celluloid gem.  Take a look at the [Github Issue](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/issues/619).

I sifted through the compass source, and it does not appear that celluloid is referenced anywhere - I am doubtful that compass is related.  If you're not using it anywhere in your project, one of your other gems must be doing so.  You'll need to run a full trace to figure out which one it is.

Comment: compass uses sass, which uses the listen gem, which uses celluloid

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?  The version of `listen` that `sass` chooses by default is dependent on this - the newest version of `listen` does not require `celluloid`.

Comment: Is upgrading to ruby 2.2 an option? The readme for `listen` *strongly* recommends using 2.2.  You may want to check the version of `listen` as well - as of 3.x, `celluloid` is no longer a dependency.

Comment: Looks like the version of listen you're using is 2.7.11.  Maybe try uninstalling that version, and upgrading to 3.x manually?

Comment: Thanks, by mistake I had fix the version in my Gemfile, after removing this and using ruby 2.2 everything works!